# Linspace in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, range, linspace

So I recently saw a post use `linspace` in Python, is this not a Matlab function? I cannot find it in the docs and was under the impression that the Python alternative for `linspace` is `range`. Is it part of some module/library/package?

Comment: Typing "python linspace" in google gives you the answer.......

Answer (score -1):

As Bylal said it's a numpy thing. Numpy mostly exists for greater easy of use and performance in mathematical functions. While you can achieve the same thing as `linspace` with a list comprehension of a range `linspace` is less verbose and much faster (plus for mathematical/scientific applications numpy's arrays are far easier to work with than python's lists and sets).

Most of what numpy does is relatively easily done in regular python code but numpy is far faster and much easier to work with.